# Comparing probabilities of two different models - apples to oranges

Tags: logistic, predictive-models, recommender-system

I have 5 logistic models for 5 products. For recommending a product to a customer, I want to rank order the products by their probability scores. The problem arises because I am comparing apples to oranges, the probability scale for each of the models is different, the penetration rate for each product is different.

I can standardize the probability but how do I include the penetration rate as well?

Comment: A method sometimes used in these contexts is to develop a segmentation for the product penetration. Based on the historical acceptance rates of the products at the leaf nodes and the probabilities of the 5 models, a subset of products might be arrived at.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I still am finding hard to implement. Maybe havent understood the approach fully. I want to recommend top 3 products to each customer using their product probabilities..